# CDbCommand failed to execute SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to create a user but every time click to create, I get this error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint       violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dcpcommunity`.`system_users`, CONSTRAINT `system_users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`party_id`) REFERENCES `parties` (`id`)). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `system_users` (`status`, `date_modified`, `username`, `password`, `date_last_login`, `date_created`, `user_role`, `isLogin`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7)
```

I read that this error means that I do not have a 'party_id' in my table, but I triple checked and party_id exists as my primary key for my system_users table.

I also see that it says REFERENCES `parties` and I checked in my model the references part and changed it to my table name and I still get this error.

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'party' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'system_users', 'party_id'),
    );
}
```

**EDIT**

```
[system_users]
pk: party_id
username
password
date_last_login
status
date_created
date_modified
user_role
isLogin
```

There is a Parties table with fields id and party_type_id

**EDIT**

I checked my db and In my system_users table, I found that party_id has a relation to :

db.parties.id

How do I make this relationship possible when creating a new record?

Comment: Could you please show us the scheme of your party and system users schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the sql error states: REFERENCES parties id... parties is a table in the db. AR will look for a AR model called Party, as the relations function states.
In the AR model "party" should be a definition where it uses the table "parties".
The error comes from the the db (schema).
The create action tries to insert a value which doesnt correspond to the schema definitions in system_users or parties.

Comment: Is there a way to make it link towards the table I want it to insert into? I generated these models through Gii so I'm not sure why it's linking to the wrong table.

Comment: What do you meam with "linking towards the table" ?

Comment: What I meant was passing the model from the controller to the view (create).

Comment: you have to extend the create action http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/